# Printing a list created by a Python function in Django

Tags: python, html, django, function

I want to take the list created by the following function (list of counters) and print that out on an HTML Django template. I know that in the HTML I'll need

```
{% for i in listofcounters %}
<p> {{ something here maybe? }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

But really the confusion is coming from where the function goes (in views.py? or is it a model?) and then how to get it so the HTML page can read it.

Also, I'm aware that what I might be doing isn't the "best" way to present this information, but this is for me to understand Django better by creating a toy project that I'm interested in. It's not for a "real" site. So, in saying that, I ask that you don't suggest anything too far outside my original question. That being "here's my function, how can I get its output in HTML form?" unless you feel it's impossible to do so.

```
from mtgsdk import Card

def findcounters():
    listofcounters = []
    cards_from_set = Card.where(set='iko').all()
    for card in cards_from_set:
        if "counter target" in str(card.text).lower():
            listofcounters.append(card.name)
    listofcounters = list(dict.fromkeys(listofcounters))
    return listofcounters
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include this in the object you pass to the render inside your view.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from mtgsdk import Card


def findcounters():
    listofcounters = []
    cards_from_set = Card.where(set='iko').all()
    for card in cards_from_set:
        if "counter target" in str(card.text).lower():
            listofcounters.append(card.name)
    listofcounters = list(dict.fromkeys(listofcounters))
    return listofcounters


def my_view(request):
    counters = findcounters()
    return render(request, 'file.html', {'counters': counters})
```

Then import this view into urls and you're off to the races!

Answer (score 0):

if I am not mistaken all you have to do is pass a `dict` to the template.
I have not tried out your code but from a quick glance that is what I got.

```
from mtgsdk import Card

def findcounters(request):
    listofcounters = []
    cards_from_set = Card.where(set='iko').all()
    for card in cards_from_set:
        if "counter target" in str(card.text).lower():
            listofcounters.append(card.name)
    listofcounters = list(dict.fromkeys(listofcounters))
    #**********try adding the following code to the code ************
    ctx = { 'listofcounter':listofcounters }

    return render(request, 'yourtemplate.html', ctx}
```

Comment: this function does not serve a request so there is no point of returning `render()`

Comment: @VishalSingh you are right, I missed that, thanks. but this still gets op closer to the solution. or is there a better way?